# How to handle *.txt requests in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, httphandler, httpmodule

I've running asp.net application under IIS7 in classic mode. 
I've already created script mapping to '*' with ISAPI module, but when i perform txt request (even if it not exists) i get 404 error with:

Notification MapRequestHandler

Handler StaticFile

and no event is fired in Global.asax or modules.
Do i missed something?

```
<system.web>
...
<httpHandlers>
    <add verb="*" path="*" validate="false" type="TestCustomExtensions.TextFileHandler, TestCustomExtensions" />
</httpHandlers>
<httpModules>
    <add name="text" type="TestCustomExtensions.TextModule"/>
</httpModules>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
...
<modules>
   <add name="textModule" type="TestCustomExtensions.TextModule"/>
</modules>
<handlers>
   <add name="TextFiles" path="*" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness32" />
</handlers>
,</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Did you register the handler in the iis in the handler mapping section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved!

The problem was in my OS. I have 64x windows installed, but in config file i set 32x path to ISAPI dll. So, to resolve this, i've added two lines, to handle both 32x and 64x OS.

```
<add name="TestFiles64" path="*.txt" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness64" />
<add name="TextFiles32" path="*.txt" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness32" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to remove the `StaticFile` handler:

```
<handlers>
    <remove name="StaticFile" />
</handlers>
```

**UPDATE**

Try the following (the order of HTTP handlers is important):

```
<handlers>
    <remove name="StaticFile" />

    <add name="TextFiles" path="*" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness32" />
    <add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule"
     resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Read" />  
</handlers>
```

Comment: but then StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule will not work

Answer (score 0):

You could use [IIS Failed Request Tracing](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/266/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-7/) to see what actually gets requested and where it fails.